# Exporting InfoPath directly to a Word document

Tags: infopath, export, word, crm

I am not a programmer!  The company I work for has been developing a CRM and quoting program using SharePoint and InfoPath.  I have been struggling because I am familiar and successful with quoting using Excel and Word to create my quotes.  The new quote program does not give me the flexibility I want/need that I currently have with Excel and Word.  My quotes can be as simple as one part or as complex as a ten page, multi-option quote combining parts and services.

I have many concerns and challenges with using our new quote program.  Some of the concerns could be alleviated if I could save or export my quotes to a word document instead of a PDF file.

Could this forum recommend a method or program to save my completed quotes from InfoPath directly to a Word document?

Comment: Hi @mtm, welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to export your completed InfoPath form (which is an XML file) to Word. Two possibilities might be useful to you though:

1. The data submitted to SharePoint can then be exported/[synced with Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-an-external-list-to-Excel-fcbb5cdc-cf49-4131-8294-21bc25e66952).
2. You can create a Print View in InfoPath that uses Word (I've never done this but it's on the Page Design tab under New View). You need to be using an InfoPath Filler form for this, not a browser form.

You may also find that InfoPath Designer itself can do what you need after all. It's got a bit of a steep learning curve, but significant capabilities once you figure it out.